# How can I generate a swagger API specification from a JAX-RS (Jersey 2) application at build time?

Tags: jax-rs, swagger

The [swagger-core documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup) describes how to incorporate swagger into the application.  Annotations are scanned at runtime.

Instead, I would like to statically generate the swagger API specification at build time.  Is this possible using swagger-core?

EDIT: We are building using ant.

Answer (score 0):

swagger-core alone is a runtime library and cannot be used to generate Swagger definitions at build time.

You can use the [swagger-maven-plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin) which depends on swagger-core to produce such definitions. However, I'd recommend browsing around the branches and using the version that produces Swagger 2.0 definitions to keep up with the latest improvements.

Comment: We build with `ant`.  Do you know if there's an option for that?

Comment: Enunciate (http://enunciate.webcohesion.com) may have an ant task but I don't know the quality of the Swagger definition it provides.

Comment: Thanks @Ron.  I looked into enunciate, but it doesn't support Java 8.

Comment: These are the two available options that I know of.